# Connect to AWS EC2 using ListSFTP processor in apache nifi

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, apache-nifi

I am trying to list files in AWS EC2 instance using ListSFTP processor(In apache nifi). 
I able to do this using FileZilla but unable to do using ListSFTP processor. I get this exception - 
[image]

I think I've set all the properties correctly in ListSFTP processor.

[image]

Also I've allowed all traffic on the EC2 instance security group.

[image]

Not sure where I am going wrong. Is it something got to do with the pem file.? What should I do.? When I give the path to the file that is on the desktop of the local computer I get error. Nifi says invalid private key path.

Comment: What are the credentials you're using in FileZilla to connect to the SFTP instance? You'll have to provide those to the `ListSFTP` processor as well. In the above configuration, it seems you've listed the OS user `ec2-user` (is that configured as the name of a valid SFTP user?). It also seems that you have not provided a password. This seems likely to result in the error you're getting.

Comment: I did not set any password for the ec2 instance. I used the same credentials that I used for Filezilla. Username - ec2-user, I left the password box empty and port - 22. It worked using filezilla.  I also set password for my ec2 instance and tried, it did not work. I imported the pem file in Filezilla but with nifi I am not doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include your key file of the remote instance to the nifi. Bring the key into the nifi instance and set the value `Private Key Path` which is `<key path>/<key name>`. Then, it will work. I've tested in my nifi.

[image]
[image]